# Using Amazon Simple Storage Service (S3) on Android

Tags: android, amazon-s3, asihttprequest

What's the best way to use Amazon Simple Storage Service (S3) on Android?

For iPhone I use ASIHTTPRequest. Is there something similar for Android?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is now an Amazon-supported Android SDK: http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforandroid/ .  It's only been out since the end of 2010, but it seems to work well - it allowed me to easily upload a photo to S3.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I think if no library exists which works with android you will need to just roll your own. Take a look at the [REST API](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/2006-03-01/API/) and implement just the methods that you need for your application.

Doing it this way is more work but you will keep the filesize of your application down.

Comment: +1 S3 is RESTful and does only expose two kinds of resources (buckets and objects). This should not be too complicated...

Comment: @moxn: writing your own generic S3 library that actually supports ACLs, etc., is reasonably complex.  That being said, writing a library that serves the needs of a specific application is much less complex.

Comment: I should add that an Amazon employee recommended using this method over at the Amazon forums.

Answer (score 0):

I think any S3 Java API should do it ? Look at the docs for Java API Libraries.

Comment: The AWS Java SDK requires third-party libraries that seem incompatible with Android.

Comment: Can you give a pointer of what is incompatible ? Link Resource or Errormessage etc ?

Comment: They need third-party jars that include java.* and javax.* packages. Even if they were compatible, the jar dependencies amount to more than 6MB, which is too much for a mobile application.